# Parse array from php file

Tags: php, file, parsing

The .php file contains code like:

```
<?php

return array(

  // commments...
  'some_item'       => 'abc',

  // commments...
  'some_other_item' => array(1, 2, 3),

  ...

);
```

What's the best way to "parse" this file somehow from within my PHP application, and be able to update data in it, without breaking formatting, code etc. ?

Comment: why would you store data in PHP code in the first place?

Comment: it's really basic data, that the application needs on start-up (b4 the db gets connected)..

Comment: Then include the file at first and give a name to the array like $myArray=Array(...); and no need to return it.

Comment: then why do you need to update it dynamically?

Comment: ok I`m going to use a ini file, I think it's easier to edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$content = require($file);` will get the file's content (beware of relative paths and `require`vs `include` semantics).

`file_put_contents($file, '<?php return ' . var_export($content, true) . ';');` will write the content back to the file, but formatting will change. If you really need to keep the formatting, you could look into [PHP Beautifier](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Beautifier/). It's not a perfect solution though.

Answer (score 5):

simply `include()` the file:

```
$my_array = include 'myarray.php';
```

See example #4 at http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Comment: what about updating the array?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to `include` it; yes, `include` returns a value!

```
$data = include 'someData.php';
```

Comment: @Alex: You don't. Use a database.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your array has only two items

```
<?php
    $myArray=include 'data.php';
    $myArray[count($myArray)]='Item-3';
    echo $myArray[2]; // Item-3
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to load filenames which are contained in an array?  If so:

```
$array_of_files = array('header.php','database.php','../inc/other_stuff.php');

foreach($array_of_files as $file)
{
   include $file;
}
```